# Updating table in SQL-Server from R

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I am downloading data from EuroStat with the R code below:

```
library(eurostat)
  tps00176<-get_eurostat("tps00176",time_format = "num")%>%
        data.frame()
```

This code works successfully, and after that, I transfer this data to SQL-Server, with code below:

```
  sqlSave(uat_conn, tps00176, tablename = "integration.tps00176",rownames=FALSE,
          varTypes = c(
            "citizen"="varchar(5)",
            "agedef"="varchar(8)",
            "age"="varchar(6)",
            "unit"="varchar(3)",
            "sex"="varchar(2)",
            "geo"="varchar(3)",
            "time"="integer",
            "values"="integer"))
```

So far, so good. But problems arise when I want to update this data after some period. I receive a message in the R that this table already exists.

```
Error in sqlSave(uat_conn, integration.tps00176, tablename = "integration.integration.tps00176",  : 
  table ‘integration.integration.tps00176’ already exists
```

So can anybody help me how to **update** this table with commands from R instead of created?

Comment: Have you tried `append=FALSE`?

Comment: @Julian I tried but nothing. Error is same

Comment: If you are confident that you want to remove any pre-existing rows, have you considered `safer=FALSE`? Are you comfortable running something like `sqlQuery(uat_conn, "drop table integration.tps00176")` and ignore the error, or use one of SQL Server's variants of `drop table if exists`?

Comment: @r2evans I am looking for a way to do this automatically. So if there is a tab in the database itself, download it, and if not, create it. That's my goal

Comment: Yes. Did you try `safer=FALSE`? That seems pretty automatic to me. (Caveat: I don't use `RODBC`, I prefer `DBI`/`odbc`.)

Comment: Specifically, from `?sqlSave`, for `safer` it reads *"If true, create a non-existing table but only allow appends to an existing table. If false, allow sqlSave to attempt to delete all the rows of an existing table, or to drop it."* Again, I haven't tried it, but my interpretation of that is that it will attempt to empty/delete the table automatically.

Comment: @Julian I tried but nothing

Comment: Seems like it's not interpreting the schema name properly. Do you use `odbcDriverConnect(interpretDot = FALSE)`?